# Is it normal for Array.filter to also be able to map an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, filter

Not sure if this is really a question but I noticed this when I accidentally didn't use an equality check when using Array.filter. Instead, it mapped my array when I feel like I should've received some kind of error for not using the equality check:

```
const x = [{ name: 'user' }];
console.log(x.filter(x => x.name = 'another user'))

// Result:
// [{ name: 'another user' }]
```

Is this documented anywhere? I feel like this isn't intended. I couldn't find anything about Array.filter also being able to map so that's why I ask it here. Maybe this belongs on github...

Comment: Typo? `x.name = 'another user'` -> `x.name === 'another user'`? -- Honestly, I didn't finish reading the question when I wrote this...

Comment: No, because this is not a syntax error (you wrote valid code), but a logic one on your part. Languages aren't obligated to report an error if you wrote valid code.

Comment: Every array methods call the callback provided on each item. You are updating each object's `x.name = 'another user'`. Also the assignment expression returns `another user` as its value. That is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value. So, every object from the original array is included in the output and updated.

Answer (score 2):

There are many array methods which may well iterate over all elements of the array unless stopped earlier somehow (such as through a thrown error, or through a falsey value returned by the callback to `Array.every`, or through a truthy value returned by the callback to `Array.find`).

These methods *can all be misused* to do something they weren't designed for. There are no exceptions, except perhaps for the generic iteration methods which were designed for side-effects.

Yes, you can misuse `.filter` as a substitution for a generic iteration method by performing side-effects inside the callback. You can also, for example, misuse `.map` the same exact way.

If you want to be able to protect yourself against these sorts of typos, consider using a linter which will warn you against it - such as with ESLint's [no-return-assign](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-assign).